# Loading a UIViewController from the stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am new to iPhone app development. I'm very confused with the concepts of views and view controllers.

My question is as follows:

I have a `UIViewController`. For the purposes of the example, let's call this one **A**.

From this I load another view controller **B** using `presentModalViewController`.

On the `presentModalViewcontroller` I push yet another view controller **C**. From this view controller I want to load the first mentioned view controller **A**. I read that these views are arranged in stacks. However I am not sure about how to do it.

How can I load the same view controller **A** in this case?

Comment: It depends what version of Xcode you're using. If you use Xcode 4, you can make use of Storyboards - http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-[UIViewController presentingViewController]` method on `C`:

```
UIViewController *A = C.presentingViewController;
```

This will return the view controller that sent `presentModalViewController:animated:`. If you want to provide information back to `A`, I'd go for delegation instead but the above works too.

---

If your question was how to get back to `A` (i.e. dismiss the modal view controller), use this:

```
UIViewController *A = C.presentingViewController;
[A dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: The first part of my answer shows how to get back a pointer to `A` so that you can send messages to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need to pop off view controllers C and B to get back to A.
If you present A on top of B and C, then they could launch B again on top and before you know it you have a huge stack of repeated views on top of each other.

Comment: Thats exactly the situation I am in right now. So is popping B and C the only solution here.

Comment: To stop you going round in circles, yes.

Comment: B is presentmodalviewcontroller and c is a viewcontroller. So what should be my code like.

Comment: I dismissed the presentmodalviewcontroller. The view is working fine. Is there anything I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `UINavigationController` to push `UIViewControllers`